# Sentence rotate program not working ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to write a program that takes a user's input (sentence), a word the user wants to rotate around, and outputs a rotated sentence around the word that has been chosen by user. 
eg. Sentence: This is a book
Word to rotate around: book
Output: book This is a

I can't seem to exit this loop of entering data (the program keeps asking for input, not doing anything more.)
Please help. Here's my code:

```
class SentenceRotator
  def get_sentence
    puts "Please enter your sentence: "
    sentence = gets.chomp
    get_word
  end

  def get_word
   puts "Please enter the word you want to rotate around: "
   word = gets.chomp
   if converts_sentence_to_array.include?(word)
     rotate_sentence_around_word
   else
     puts "Your word isn't in the sentence. Please enter another word."
     word = gets.chomp
   end
   rotate_sentence_around_word
  end

  def converts_sentence_to_array()
    get_sentence.split(" ")
  end

  def rotate_sentence_around_word()
    new_array = converts_sentence_to_array.each_with_index {|word,index| converts_sentence_to_array.rotate(index)}
    new_array
  end
end

new_app = SentenceRotator.new
new_app.rotate_sentence_around_word
```

Comment: You don't really _need_ to get a new sentence each time you enter `converts_sentence_to_array`. You should split the tasks of requesting new user input and retrieving previously entered data. So  that you request one time, but later can refer to that input many times.

Comment: For input "This is a very funny book", and rotate on "a", what would be the output?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh output should be: a very funny book This is

Comment: @SergioTulentsev could u pls explain with some code?

Comment: @ChristianDziwornu: yeah, I understand those words may not mean anything, but I don't have the time to go deeper here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new_app = SentenceRotator.new
new_app.rotate_sentence_around_word
```

So, calling methods: `rotate_sentence_around_word` => `converts_sentence_to_array` => `get_sentence` => `get_word` => `converts_sentence_to_array` => `get_sentence` => ...

Try something like this:

```
class SentenceRotator
  def gets_user_data
    puts "Please enter your sentence: "
    @sentence = get_sentence.split(" ")

    puts "Please enter the word you want to rotate around: "
    @word = get_word_to_rotate_on
  end

  def get_sentence
    gets.chomp
  end

  def get_word_to_rotate_on
    word = gets.chomp
    return word if @sentence.include?(word)

    puts "Your word isn't in the sentence. Please enter another word."
    get_word_to_rotate_on
  end

  def rotate_sentence_around_word()
    gets_user_data
    @sentence.rotate(@sentence.index(@word)).join(' ')
  end
end

new_app = SentenceRotator.new
new_app.rotate_sentence_around_word
```

Comment: You can replace `word = gets.chomp` with `word = get_sentence`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the logic you want, split up into separate lines:

```
# input
sentence = 'This is a book'
word = 'book'

# processing
words = sentence.split
pos = words.index(word)
rotated = words.rotate(pos)
back_together = rotated.join(' ')

# output
p back_together
```

I'd advise you to separate out your processing code as much as possible. Then you can focus on the terminal input and output logic, which is what actually seems to be your issue.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't seem to exit this loop of entering data (the program keeps asking for input, not doing anything more.)

It looks like your foremost problem is to take the input from user properly and enter the rotation logic. You could make use of [`attr_reader`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_reader) to access the input across methods. I have made some changes to your class to accept the input in multiple steps:

```
class SentenceRotator
  attr_reader :sentence, :rotate_on_word

  def get_sentence
    puts "Please enter your sentence: "
    @sentence = gets.chomp
  end

  def get_word_to_rotate_on
    puts "Please enter the word you want to rotate around: "
    @rotate_on_word = gets.chomp
    unless sentence.include?(rotate_on_word)
      puts "Your word isn't in the sentence. Please enter another word."
      get_word_to_rotate_on
    end
  end

  def rotate
    puts sentence
    puts rotate_on_word
    puts 'You have all the info. Add the logic to rotate.'
  end
end

> new_app = SentenceRotator.new

> new_app.get_sentence
Please enter your sentence: 
This is a very funny book

> new_app
 => #<SentenceRotator:0x00007fee44178c40 @sentence="This is a very funny book">

> new_app.get_word_to_rotate_on
Please enter the word you want to rotate around: 
a

> new_app
 => #<SentenceRotator:0x00007fee44178c40 @sentence="This is a very funny book", @rotate_on_word="a">

> new_app.rotate
This is a very funny book
a
You have all the info. Add the logic to rotate.
```